# Using the Ends With jquery selector and get the options of a listbox

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("input[id$=UserField_hiddenSpanData],input[title=Title]").each(function(){

    var rb = $('#ctl00_m_g_c6ae303a_6013_4adb_8057_63a214bcfd24_ctl00_ctl04_ctl07_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_SelectResult option').length;
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val != 0 && val.length != 0 && rb != 0) { 

        //add one to the counter
        controlsPassed += 1;
    }

    });
```

It works fine but I don't want to have the ID hardcoded so I thought I could use

```
var rb = $('id$=SelectResult option').length;
```

but it doesn't work, what's wrong with my syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need brackets on your [ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), like this:

```
var rb = $('[id$=SelectResult] option').length;
```

It'll be faster with the element selector on there though:

```
var rb = $('select[id$=SelectResult] option').length;
```

Another thought as stated in comments on a prior question, there's no need to repeat this check every time in the loop, you can do it outside once :)